# Ajax - dynamically create a button for post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I need to dynamically assign an id on a  element to make a POST request and then add a class to another element. I'm really a noob with JS, so I think i made a mess..

Basically, i have a jsp page with a forEach loop that creates rows. In the last  I have a link to click which sends a POST request. With the result of the request (a boolean T/F) i need to apply a class on the  element.

The problem is how to create a dynamic id to pass to the script, and how to select the  to add a class based on the POST result.

My jsp has this forEach loop

```
<c:forEach items="${notifications }" var="notification">
    <tr id="${notification.notificationId }">
        <td class="actions pull-right"><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

the script is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#${notification.notificationId").closest('a').click(function(){  
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/${notification.notificationId}',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (text) {
                    $("#${notification.notificationId"}).addClass("font-bold");
                    alert(text);
                })
        })
    })
```

obviously it does not work, because `$("#${notification.notificationId"})` it's not correct (i don't know if the rest of the script works too...

Comment: Instead what you could do is assign a data attribute to the tr. IE: data-notification-id="${notification.notificationId }". Also add a class to each click able tr. Then in the jquery use the class ($'.tr-class').on('click', function(e){ var id = $(this).data('notification-id').... then the rest of your stuff...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to get the click link row container. You select the element that was clicked and get it's parent until you the the right container.
Above a example of what you maybe have to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("tr > td > a").on("click", function (e) {
      // This will prevent your link to navigate to "#"
      e.preventDefault();

      // This is the container row of the link that was clicked
      var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();

      // The ajax request
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/" + $tr.attr("id"), // This will take the ID of the row container. Eg: ID=1 it will navigate to "/1"
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
          // I presume that you response will be either "true" or "false" like you mention
          // So, if the response is "true", then we add the class to the row container
          if (response == "true") {
            $tr.addClass("font-bold");
          }

        });

      });

    });

});
```

Good luck!